# Section and subsection formatting

Tags: sectioning, formatting, subsection

I am using this academic CV template from Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/academic-cv-template/hvjpfjnyggbf. Please, consider that template as the MWE.

I want to modify the `\cvsection` and `\cvsubsection` commands so that they act like the standard `\section` and `\subsection` commands in LaTeX.

This means that they should have numbers, be included in the table of contents, but keeping the same formatting as in the template.

How can I do this?

The `\cvsection` and `\cvsubsection` are defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionTopSkip}
  \sectionstyle{#1} 
  \phantomsection
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
}

\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-3mm}
  \subsectionstyle{#1}
  \phantomsection
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to actually have a numbered CV with a table of contents, or do you just like the format of these sections and want to use them in a regular document?

Comment: You are right, @AlanMunn. My aim is to have an indexed CV so it is easy to access to each of the sections of the CV.  I don't actually care the solution... change the format of the sections.... or make the cvsection behave like a section. I just need the cvsection  forma to be indexed as a section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `academic-cv` class defines its own sectioning commands, so you are right that these are what need to be changed. So the following additions need to be made to the class:

First, we make some counters for the sections:

```
\newcounter{cvsection}
\newcounter{cvsubsection}[cvsection]
\renewcommand\thecvsubsection{\thecvsection.\arabic{cvsubsection}}
```

Next we redefine the sectioning commands to write to the TOC. Notice that although the commands are called `\cvsection` and `\cvsubsection` when we write to the TOC, we use `section` and `subsection` since these correspond to *levels* of the TOC format, not actual command names.

```
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionTopSkip}
  \refstepcounter{cvsection}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thecvsection.\quad#1}
  \sectionstyle{\thecvsection.\quad#1} 
  \phantomsection
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
}

\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-3mm}
  \refstepcounter{cvsubsection}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\normalfont\thecvsubsection.~#1}
  \subsectionstyle{\thecvsubsection.\quad #1}
  \phantomsection
}
```

Finally we use the `tocloft` package to adjust the TOC format as needed.

```
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2em}
```

Now in the main document, we can simply add `\tableofcontents` and we get the following output. Obviously you may want to issue a `\clearpage` command after the TOC.  Any further formatting of the TOC can be done using `tocloft` as needed.

[image: first page of outpu]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!